# Can't send broadcast from worker thread to main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, rest, broadcastreceiver, localbroadcastmanager

I am trying to implement an architecture similar to the one presented at the Android Developer Summit 2015: https://github.com/yigit/dev-summit-architecture-demo. My application has a simple class that handles the network requests. The class uses Retrofit 2 for the requests. I am also using Dagger 2 for dependency injection.

I am trying to achieve something very simple. My activity tells a controller to fetch data. The controller then makes a call to my REST client to perform a network request. When the request completes successfully I want to broadcast an event to my Activity so that it can update the UI. However, the event is not being broadcast.

I am using the LocalBroadcastManager to broadcast events. My activity registers/unregisters for broadcasts in the onResume/onPause methods. My REST client has an instance of the application context which is provided through dependency injection. The REST client uses the application context to send the broadcast.

My first suspicion was that the broadcasts were not being sent because the network requests are executed on a worker thread whereas the activity is expecting broadcasts on the main thread. However, this type of scenario shouldn't be a problem if the Android documentation is correct.

This is my activity.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ApplicationComponent mApplicationComponent;
    private EventBroadcastReceiver mEventBroadcastReceiver = new EventBroadcastReceiver();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mApplicationComponent = getMovieManagerApplication().getApplicationComponent();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("now_playing");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mEventBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mEventBroadcastReceiver);
    }

    protected MovieManagerApplication getMovieManagerApplication() {
        return (MovieManagerApplication) getApplication();
    }

    protected ApplicationComponent getApplicationComponent() {
        return mApplicationComponent;
    }

    protected void update(Intent intent) {

    }

    private class EventBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            update(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my REST client.

```
public class MovieRestClient extends BaseRestClient implements Callback<MovieResponse> {

    @Inject
    public MovieApiService mMovieApiService;

    @Inject
    public Context mApplicationContext;

    public MovieRestClient(ApplicationComponent applicationComponent) {
        super(applicationComponent);
        getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<MovieResponse> response) {
        if (response.isSuccess()) {
            Parcelable parcelable = Parcels.wrap(response.body());
            MovieResponse movieResponse = Parcels.unwrap(parcelable);
            Intent intent = new Intent("now_playing");
            intent.putExtra(MovieResponse.class.getName(), parcelable);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mApplicationContext).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

    }

    public void getNowPlaying() {
        mMovieApiService.getNowPlaying(API_KEY).enqueue(this);
    }

    public void getPopular() {
        mMovieApiService.getPopular(API_KEY).enqueue(this);
    }

    public void getTopRated() {
        mMovieApiService.getTopRated(API_KEY).enqueue(this);
    }

    public void getUpcoming() {
        mMovieApiService.getUpcoming(API_KEY).enqueue(this);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it fixed? I'm also stuck in worker thread scenario.